# Creating games in OpenGL ES in java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I would like to create game in opengl on Android, but I don't know how ;/
I can make an application on Android, so I am not noob :D
Can you give me a link to tutorial: how can I make a 3d game in OpenGl?
I read a [jayway tutorial](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-ii-building-a-polygon/) but it isn't about making games.

Comment: I believe this belongs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check on [GameDev.net forums](http://www.gamedev.net/index).

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is just a drawing API. It's not a game engine or scene graph or any other kind of sophisticated thing. It gives you some canvas and some drawing tools to paint on it with. OpenGL is just the very last step in the data processing steps of a game.

You have to implement some game logic and whatever that one spits out you can use to draw pictures using OpenGL. But you'll have to carry out all drawing steps yourself, if you use OpenGL.